# NFS - mv command from two clients file corruption?

Tags: linux, race-condition, nfs, corruption, file-locking

I have  a basic script that I want to do the following :

1. if new/file.txt exists
2. mv new/file.txt current/file.txt

Now - if 2 servers were to run this same script at the same exact time (having access to the same NFS file share) :

- Server 1 - step 1. checks if file exists. True
- Server 2 - step 1. checks if file exists. True
- Server 1 - step 2. starts to perform the "mv" command
- Server 2 - step 2. ????

From what I can find online, it looks like an error would just get thrown by Server 2 - but no file corruption or anything should be of concern :
http://nfs.sourceforge.net/

> The file handle refers to a deleted file. After a file is deleted on
>   the server, clients don't find out until they try to access the file
>   with a file handle they had cached from a previous LOOKUP. Using rsync
>   or **mv to replace a file while it is in use on another client** is a
>   common scenario that results in an ESTALE error.

I've tried simulating this to confirm but haven't been able to do so successfully - so I wanted to check here before implementing this strategy :

Question :
**Is my understanding accurate - or do I need to use a different strategy to ensure the file.txt doesn't get corrupted?**

Additional details : 
Amazon Linux OS. The drive is mounted is **nsf4**. The file could be as large as 100MB

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, can you please provide a reason so I can adjust the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The check-if-file-exists is a typical [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem.

The simplest fix is to just *not* check, and **try** to `mv`.
If there is no file to be moved, the `mv` will fail (and not do anything).

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Is there a possibility that server 1 starts to perform the `mv` and server 2 tries to `mv` prior to server 1 finishing  (i.e. I'd guess the file still appears visible in the source directory) ? Or is this controlled through some mutex / lock at the file system level ?